# python watchdog error: OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I am trying to run a function every time a file changes. Watchdog seems to be the main solution to do this without polling.

My code however returns an error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-14:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 146, in run
    self.queue_events(self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\read_directory_changes.py", line 77, in queue_events
    winapi_events = read_events(self._handle, self.watch.is_recursive)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\winapi.py", line 347, in read_events
    buf, nbytes = read_directory_changes(handle, recursive)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\winapi.py", line 307, in read_directory_changes
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\winapi.py", line 303, in read_directory_changes
    ctypes.byref(nbytes), None, None)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\winapi.py", line 108, in _errcheck_bool
    raise ctypes.WinError()
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect.
```

The code is straight from the documentation and pasted below:

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        print("Got it!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_handler = MyHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path='C:/Email_forwarding/Attachments/Sales/test.txt', recursive=False)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

I am running Python 3.6 (Anaconda) on Windows Server 2012 with watchdog 0.8.3.

Edit: tried downgrading to Python 3.5.2 but still get the same error.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Watchdog?

Comment: Yes, watchdog 0.8.3.

Comment: I checked the source code on GitHub and compared to the Windows API and couldn't find anything obviously wrong. Now, I don't know anything about Windows programming and only very little about the ctypes library used by Watchdog, so I'd suggest that you raise an issue on GitHub about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your file path to the parent folder path.

`observer.schedule(event_handler, path='C:/Email_forwarding/Attachments/Sales', recursive=False)`

Comment: I suppose that it worked but what would you do if you had to watch only a single file?

Comment: @george-sp: reject all files except yours in event_handler. You are welcome.